# Flutter - Align text in table

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I align text in my `Table`?

From left for first column (`ID`) and from right for second column (`Value`).

```
    child: Table(                    
                        children: [
                          TableRow(children: [
                            TableCell(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text('ID'),
                                  new Text('Value'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` instead of `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`